# Javascript search engine doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a custom JS search filter. to search tagname 'h2' letter by letter. 
For example: `<h2>CHOCOLATE MOUSSE</h2>`, `<h2>SMOKED LAMB WITH RICE</h2>`

When typing "mo" on search bar, both "display = block". When typing "mou", first one "display = block", second "display = none";

Here is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <script src="./chat.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col">
        <div id="search-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="input">
        </div>     
</div>
<main>          
    <div class="recipe a">
        <h2>CHOCOLATE MOUSSE</h2>
        <p class="description">
            This delicious chocolate mousse will delight dinner guests of all ages!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe b">
        <h2>SMOKED LAMB WITH RICE</h2>
        <p class="description">
            Want to feel like your favorite relative came over and made you dinner? This comfort meal of smoked lamb and rice will quickly become a weekend favorite!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe c">
        <h2>GOAT CHEESE SALAD</h2>
        <p class="description">
            In addition to the full flavor of goat cheese, this salad includes kale, avocado, and farro to balance it out.</p>
    </div>
</main>
```

Here is my javascript function

```
const searchBar = document.forms['search-box'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    const term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const words = list.getElementsByTagName('h2');
    Array.from(words).forEach(function(word){
        const title = word.firstElementChild.textContent;
            if(title.toLowerCase().includes(term)!= -1){
            word.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            word.style.display = 'none';
        }
    })
})
```

Why javascript code does nothing on my HTML? 
Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const searchBar = document.querySelector('div#search-box > input');

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    let term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let words = document.querySelectorAll('div.recipe > h2');

    Array.from(words).forEach(function(word){
        let title = word.textContent;
        if(title.toLowerCase().includes(term)){
            word.parentElement.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            word.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
});
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
        <script src="./chat.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="col">
          <div id="search-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="input">
          </div>     
        </div>
        <main>          
          <div class="recipe a">
            <h2>CHOCOLATE MOUSSE</h2>
            <p class="description">
            This delicious chocolate mousse will delight dinner guests of all ages!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="recipe b">
            <h2>SMOKED LAMB WITH RICE</h2>
            <p class="description">
            Want to feel like your favorite relative came over and made you dinner? This comfort meal of smoked lamb and rice will quickly become a weekend favorite!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="recipe c">
            <h2>GOAT CHEESE SALAD</h2>
            <p class="description">
            In addition to the full flavor of goat cheese, this salad includes kale, avocado, and farro to balance it out.</p>
          </div>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Few problems were found in your vanilla JS:

1. Your search box is not a form, it's in a div tag.  Solution: use document.querySelector directly on the search box's input field.
2. The 'list' variable was not declared anywhere, but by the look of your syntax, I assumed you were anticipating an array of items and extract text from their h2 tags.  Solution: use document.querySelectorAll to find all h2 instances inside the recipe divs.
3. To get the text from the h2 tags, you can directly access it by .textContent.
4. string.includes() -> returns a boolean value which is directly evaluated by the if function. That means removing '!= -1'
5. The hiding elements mechanism is off because of word(h2) is wrapped by a div element. Solution: use .parentElement to get the div element and set the style of the div to none/block instead.
6. Always use 'let' keyword as much as possible to avoid the scope monster -> That would be a separate topic.  :D